# Build not displayed on AppConnect (app store dev center)

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile

We build a Cordova app, build the app as Distribution and Release and push the code via Xcode to AppConnect.

The App is validated in Xcode (green tick), and in Activity Tab, we can see that the build is in "processing" state.

But after some time (2-3 minutes) the build is not displayed in activity anymore, nor in the app section. AppConnect still asks "Select Build" in the section but it's empty, 0 Build selectable. We have 0 error from Apple email or anything.

When we try to push it again, Xcode tell us the build is already uploaded (redundant Binary)

We are stuck. We tried to change certificate, we triple check Build Type etc.. but nothing... Any idea where to find log, what we could have missed? Is it because of Cordova? We use an iframe, is that the cause?

One more thing, we cause an error on Xcode build about missing 150 and 124 picture (not missing for the record) We found a command line to fix the error, but perhaps it's causing a bug somewhere (we sometime receive the same error by email)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wait for about 30-60 minutes, your app is being processed in the AppStoreConnect. It's normal.

Comment: We did, after the processing, it's removed from Activity. We have build package since 5 days now, still nothing...